# How to run a function inside a body of SWIFT UI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

i'm trying to run a function inside a body. i'm not familiar how functions work in swiftUI.
here's the code below.

```
struct HomeView: View {        
    
    func getDirectory() -> String{
        let fm = FileManager.default
        let path = Bundle.main.resourcePath!

        do {
            let items = try fm.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: path)

            for item in items {
                print("Found \(item)")
            }
        } catch {
            // failed to read directory – bad permissions, perhaps?
        }
        
        return path
    }
    
    
    let documentURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: resourceURL, withExtension: "pdf")!
    
    var body: some View {
        let path = getDirectory()         
        
        print(path)
    }

}
```

i'm getting an error saying.

''Function declares an opaque return type, but has no return statements in its body from which to infer an underlying type''

how can i make this work?

Comment: You should not do that, because `body` is call on every view refresh to render content. Do it instead in any action closure, like `.onAppear`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var body: some View {
    let noView: EmptyView = {
        /*
         Do what you want here
         */
        return EmptyView()
    }()
    noView
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell what you're trying to get from this document, but to answer your question directly, you need to provide a View within the body, not a String. You can add a Text that accepts a String parameter:

```
var body: some View {
    Text(getDirectory())
}
```